# "The sketched one"

Tags: expressions, slang

I'm new in the English world.

This is my questions: can I say the sentence "the sketched one" to indicate a draft version of a work?

Is it correct in english?

Comment: *Sketched* usually means hastily drawn.  *Sketched out* means outlined, which might work fora rough draft.  Please include the full sentence you're asking about.

Comment: @deadrat The full sentence could be something like "This is the sketched one.", to indicate the draft version, but probably it have no meaning...

Comment: See my comment to SB's answer.  *One* is fine in response to "Which one?" and it doesn't matter that it's at the end of the sentence.  *Sketched* is inapt here because it can't mean what you want unless you're talking about a study for a painting.  Do you mean *sketchy*, which means lacking in detail?  Or do you mean outlined only roughly?

Comment: @deadrat I mean *sketchy*

Comment: @deadrat She apparently meant *sketched*. See below. Also, *sketchy* means *iffy* and *questionable* w/r/t people and isn't in much use w/r/t versions of any drafts of any kinds of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to English!

*The sketched one* isn't a sentence but it could be a correct answer to certain questions. Usually we say *sketch*, *draft*, or other specific nouns (because we know those words and they're shorter and easier to say), but if there were several rough drafts and only one of them was *sketched* (hastily and loosely outlined in pencil or ink) and someone asked a question and it was the answer... well, then you could say that... if you're talking about a work of art drawn in that way. If you're talking about something else, like a novel or powerpoint presentation, there are other words you need to use.

You seem confused about what *one* is doing here. It's standing in for another word that we don't want to repeat. "Which picture did we decide to use?" "The sketched one" (=picture). "Which boy did we like?" "The green one" (=boy). There *has* to be an earlier, understood word that it's replacing or it doesn't make sense.

Its placement at the end of the sentence is completely unimportant.

Comment: Thank you @Ily. Yes, I'm a bit confused but your answer is really clear. So, if there are two works on a table, one is the "final" version and the other one is a draft version (hastily drawn), can I say something like: "This is the final version and *this is the sketched one*"? Or is this a wrong sentence?

Comment: If you're talking about drawings and only one of the two is *sketched* (=drawn in a loose, rough manner), then it's not *wrong*.

All the same, it's more common to use a matching pair of words. (An English teacher might insist you use them.) For example, *final version* and *first draft*; *finished product* and *initial outline*; *inked version* and *sketched one*; &c.

Answer (score 0):

No. "One" would never be correct here (it could be "thing"), and "sketched" means "drawn quickly by hand", and doesn't really work as an adjective.

You probably mean **draft**, or possibly **sketch** or **rough version**.

Comment: Thank you. But is "the **sketch** one." correct? Or the word "one" is wrong at the end of a sentence?

Comment: I'm not clear on what "here" means, but *one* would be acceptable in the following exchange: *A: Do you have the draft copy? B: Which one? A: The revised **one** I sketched out yesterday.*

Comment: *One* could be perfectly correct. It just has to follow an earlier question.

Comment: "One" would be ok after an adjective ("the latest one"), but "sketched" is probably not acceptable as an adjective (or would maybe be ok in a very specific question like "The picture that was painted or sketched?"). "The one I sketched" would be more grammatical, but I don't think "sketched" is the word you want.